# Split string by two characters in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

Him I would like to split  string by two characters.

For example I have string like this one:
 `"xx-aa-[aa]-22-[bb]"`. 
I want to retrieve string array of `[aa]` and `[bb]`. All characters between [ ].

First I can split by `'-'`, so I'll have string array

```
var tmp = myString.Split('-');
```

But now how can I retrieve only strings between `[]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following `regex`:

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

Use **global flag** to match all the groups.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cU7mM4/2)

**Explanation**

1. `()`: Capturing Group
2. `\[`: Matches `[` literal. Need to escape using `\`
3. `.+?`: Non-greedy match any number of any characters
4. `\]`: Matches `]` literal. Need to escape using `\`

**Visualization**

[image]